# BigQuery command 'bq mk' throwing the error "BigQuery error in mk operation: Error reading schema:"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery, I am trying to create BigQuery table using a BASH file, which I am running from the Cloud Shell. The file contains the following `bq mk` command:

```
bq mk --table project_id:dataset_name.table_name /home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json
```

Contents of `temp_schema.json`:

```
[
  {
    "description": "quarter",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "qtr",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "sales representative",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "rep",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "total sales",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "sales",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }
]
```

I am using the [following](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets) documentation and command as reference:

```
 bq mk --table mydataset.mytable ./myschema.json
```

The full error I am getting is:

```
BigQuery error in mk operation: Error reading schema: "/home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json
" looks like a filename, but was not found.

   bq_create_eventTables.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
   bq_create_eventTables.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
   bq_create_eventTables.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
   bq_create_eventTables.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
```

What would be the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what cat `/home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json` returns? It might be that does not exists or the BQ utility doesn't have permission to read.

Comment: I am able to read JSON file                                              aror031@cloudshell:~$ cat /home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json
[
  {
    "description": "quarter",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "qtr",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "sales representative",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "rep",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "total sales",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "sales",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

In the first command you defined the `JSON` file as `temp_schema.json` but in the second `bq mk` command  you've named it as `myschema.json`, I believe you should be pointing it to the location of `myschema.json` instead.

Comment: 2nd one is example, which I am referring.

Comment: @BhageshArora Well the output of the error is pretty straight forward - it expects a file that does not find. Could be a hidden characters issue. I see a space before the last double quotes at `"/home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json "` that does not appear on my end when I give it the wrong file name. Try re-creating the file in a local directory and re-running the command.

Comment: Given the errors related to carriage return `\r`, I strongly suspect it could be due to  hidden characters, perhaps in the bash file that are causing it.

Comment: There is no extra space & new line,and location is also fine, I have created JSON file from scratch But still getting Error - BigQuery error in mk operation: Error reading schema: "/home/bhagesharora/temp_schema.json
" looks like a filename, but was not found.